# the page load event execute twice

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ado.net

**if have this link in word file when click it open the page offers.aspx**
http://localhost:54818/offerslinks/offers.aspx?Offerid=80

**and in the page load I wrote this code**

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // GET THE ID OF THE OFFER 
            string id = Request.QueryString["Offerid"];
            // GET THE LINK AND THE LINK COUNT 
          
            if (id != null)
            {
                string linkName = "";
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpOfferbyId", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter paramid = new SqlParameter("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(id));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramid);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        linkName = rdr["Link"].ToString();
                       
                    }

                    Response.Redirect(linkName,false);
                    id = string.Empty;
                }

            }//end if 

            
        }
```

**when I made debugging I found the query string read the parameter and execute the code**
1- execute the page-load of page content
2- execute the page-load of the master page
3- ec=xecute the page-load of the **content page again**

ps: there is no anything the page

Comment: 1 and 2 are perfectly normal and should be happening in that order. But what makes you think step 3 is happening?

Comment: I made debugging I found that once execute the content the page load twice and once again execute 1  2,3   the do not know the cause of execute twice